# Site not fully loading CSS but All files are loading

Tags: html, css

My website is: http://seompg.com/

There was definitely more to the website. It had a grayish background with more color schemes. Now since I migrated servers, it looks all blank. It almost looks like some CSS files are not loading. However, looking in console, everything seems to be loading just fine.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I see 403 Forbidden error on one of your theme files which might be related to custom styles?

```
http://seompg.com/wp-content/themes/3clicks/css/g1-dynamic-style.php
```

Please investigate that why this file is being given this error on the new server , I am sure you will get closer to solving the issue you are facing with custom styles.